# Keep autolayout view same size in 3.5" and 4"

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, autolayout

I have a tracker that is 320 pixels tall that goes in the center(ish) of the screen of my app and I want to place labels in the four corners of the tracker, so I made an invisible view the size of the tracker so that I could align the labels to the view's edges, but autolayout keeps resizing the view when the tracker remains 320 pixels. Is there a way to keep my view the same size (390px) on both 3.5" and 4" iPhone screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add fixed width and height constraints to your view. Select your view and then chose Pin/Width and/or Pin/Height from the editor menu. The pin menu is also available from the middle segment in that control thingy in the lower left corner of Interface Builder.

To keep your layout from being ambiguous you then might have to remove some constraints from the size inspector of the utility area.